# Handle dblclick in Fullcalendar jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I know that this question has been asked before, but several new versions have been released since then.

Is it possible to handle a dblclick event for creating a new appointment in the calendar without having to modify the fullcalendar.js file? It would be great to handle this extension in a separate file together with my other tweaks.

Thanks in advance!

/Adam

Answer (score 29):

Adam's post at https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=231 uses this solution.

> whenever possible i like to keep things out of the core of
>   fullcalendar, and have people do them through the api. the only reason
>   i have eventClick/eventMouseover/eventMouseout as part of the core is
>   b/c they involve some special cases, such as conflicting with jquery
>   ui dragging & resizing, so i need to do things like check for those
>   classes.
>
> i think the best way to attach event handlers like dblclick would be
>   through eventRender like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.bind('dblclick', function() {
         alert('double click!');
      });
   }
})
```

> please let me know if you feel differently. thanks

I have the newest update and this works great for me.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't this solution only work when you click on already created events?

Comment: correct, but the logic is the same for dayclick, or any other click option. What kind of click are you using? I'll see if I can work something up for you.

Comment: Ok. I want to be able to double click or drag and drop on a empty slot in the week or day view to create a new event. A new event should not be created if you just click once. I know that it is possible to do workarounds to get that functionality but it would be nice to accomplish this in a cleaner way :)

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood what you were wanting to do. Adam is going to develop a dayRender event for the calendar that will allow you to do this. At the moment I don't think that this is possible without modifying the js. I will say this, there is apparently a patch that you can try, but I don't know how far you will get, I have not tried it or heard of how well it functions. Check it out and let me know if it works. http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=191

Comment: I need to have both the event single click and double click. For that i have bind dblclick and click and write alert but evev i double click i gives me ckick function as alert. What i do to get this solve

Comment: Not really sure... Untested, but you may be able to use something along the lines of an if statement to check if double click was used within your click function and if it was not used than perform your action. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 12):

I ran across the same issue and didn't want to fiddle with the core, so I wrote double-click logic into the dayClick callback.

```
dayClick:function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
            var singleClick = date.toUTCString();

            if(doubleClick==singleClick){
                console.log('Double-click!');
                doubleClick = null;
            }else{
                doubleClick=date.toUTCString();
                clearInterval(clickTimer);
                clickTimer = setInterval(function(){
                    doubleClick = null;
                    clearInterval(clickTimer);
                }, 500);
            }
        }
```

`clickTimer` and `doubleClick` are declared before the call to initialize the calendar.

Comment: this throws an error `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'date.toUTCString()')`

Comment: Use `date.format();` instead of  `date.toUTCString()`

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to [Juan Gonzales's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8143130/662581) answer:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    dayRender: function(date, element, view){
        element.bind('dblclick', function() {
            alert('double click!');
        });
    }
});
```

This code will create the `dblclick` event to the whole "day" event.

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=191#hc13)

Comment: This is definitely the simplest way to do it. For dayRender there's a problem though because the 'fc-content-skeleton' div is overlaid on top of the day elements and the dblclick event doesn't pass through. I fixed this with a little css:
`.fc-content-skeleton {
     pointer-events: none;
    }
    .fc-event {
     pointer-events: all; }`

Comment: Why this is not the main answer? It's simple and correct! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Below code shows double click events for Event & Day.
**For day,You need to double click on lower side (lower half) of date cell. I don't know the reason behind this**

```
 $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
      },
      events: this.EventList,
      defaultView: 'month',
      editable: true,
      //for event double click
      eventRender:function(event,element){
        element.bind('dblclick',function(){
          alert('double click event')
        });
      },
      //for day double click
      dayRender:function(date,cell)
      {
        cell.bind('dblclick',function(){
          alert(date)
        })
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so this is probably and old thread but I am going to give my five cents to this one. Since the version 2 (currently 2.4.0) it appears there is a bit different piece of code managing the click events. So.. this is how i solved it.

As previous stated, open fullcalendar.js, search for something like "trigger('eventClick'" and you will hit some code that looks like this:

```
$.each(
{
    mouseenter: function(seg, ev) {
        _this.triggerSegMouseover(seg, ev);
    },
    mouseleave: function(seg, ev) {
        _this.triggerSegMouseout(seg, ev);
    },
    click: function(seg, ev) {
        return view.trigger('eventClick', this, seg.event, ev); // can return `false` to cancel
    },
    mousedown: function(seg, ev) {
        if ($(ev.target).is('.fc-resizer') && view.isEventResizable(seg.event)) {
            _this.segResizeMousedown(seg, ev, $(ev.target).is('.fc-start-resizer'));
        }
        else if (view.isEventDraggable(seg.event)) {
            _this.segDragMousedown(seg, ev);
        }
    }
}, and so on .......
```

so to get the doubleclick, just get this litte piece of code inbetween click and mousedown (or whatever suits your desire):

```
dblclick: function(seg, ev) {
        return view.trigger('eventDoubleClick', this, seg.event, ev); // can return `false` to cancel
    },
```

Now, all you need to do is to specifiy it on the initialization object.

```
eventDoubleClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
    alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
    alert('View: ' + view.name);

    // change the border color just for fun
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
}
```

Worked in Chrome for me, have not tested this solution anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Use selector jquery `$(info.el).on` to bind dblclick in `eventRender`
Note : Solution just for fullcalendar V4)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       eventRender: function(info) {
            $(info.el).on('dblclick', function() {
               alert('double click!');
            });
       }
})
```

it works for me ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by modifying the *fullcalendar.js* which didn't seem like a big deal to me. Anyways, here is how you add a double click event:

- Open fullcalendar.js, search for something like "**trigger('eventClick'**"
- You will see this function:

  ```
  function eventElementHandlers(event, eventElement) {
      eventElement
      .click(function (ev) {
          if (!eventElement.hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging') &&
              !eventElement.hasClass('ui-resizable-resizing')) {
              return trigger('eventClick', this, event, ev);
          }
      })
                  .hover(
          function (ev) {
              trigger('eventMouseover', this, event, ev);
          },
          function (ev) {
              trigger('eventMouseout', this, event, ev);
          }
      );
      // TODO: don't fire eventMouseover/eventMouseout *while* dragging is occuring (on subject element)
      // TODO: same for resizing
  }
  ```
- Add this function to the eventElement's function (next to click / hover)

  ```
    .dblclick(function (ev) {
          return trigger('eventDblClick', this, event, ev);
      })
  ```
- Now you can write the double click event for the calendar event by **eventDblClick**. Something like this: (Refer to the documentation's **[eventClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/)** for the parameters)

  ```
  eventDblClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
     // Create a new appointment
  }
  ```

**Note:** You can add any jquery function to the event this way!

Comment: I like what you've done here but for some reason the 'eventDblClick' isn't firing.

Answer (score 1):

```
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            prevTime = typeof currentTime === 'undefined' || currentTime === null
                ? new Date().getTime() - 1000000
                : currentTime;
            currentTime = new Date().getTime();

            if (currentTime - prevTime < 500)
            {
                //double click call back
                console.log("this is double click");
            }
        },
```

get current time for dayClick

Answer (score 1):

Updated [Nullorado's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34656669/3772543) to v3.2.0:

Since version 3 (currently 3.2.0) it appears there is a bit different piece of code managing the click events. A good way to solve it seems as followed:

Open fullcalendar.js, search for something like "bindSegHandlersToEl" and you will hit some code that looks like this:

```
bindSegHandlersToEl: function(el) {
    this.bindSegHandlerToEl(el, 'touchstart', this.handleSegTouchStart);
    this.bindSegHandlerToEl(el, 'mouseenter', this.handleSegMouseover);
    this.bindSegHandlerToEl(el, 'mouseleave', this.handleSegMouseout);
    this.bindSegHandlerToEl(el, 'mousedown', this.handleSegMousedown);
    this.bindSegHandlerToEl(el, 'click', this.handleSegClick);
},
```

Within the above shown function, add this line to create a doubleclick handler:

```
this.bindSegHandlerToEl(el, 'dblclick', this.handleSegDoubleClick);
```

After this, look for "handleSegClick" a few lines below the function. You'll find this:

```
    handleSegClick: function(seg, ev) {
    var res = this.view.publiclyTrigger('eventClick', seg.el[0], seg.event, ev); // can return `false` to cancel
    if (res === false) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
},
```

**Copy** it and rename:

1. "handleSegClick" to "handleSegDoubleClick"
2. "eventClick" to "eventDoubleClick"

You end up with the following:

```
handleSegDoubleClick: function(seg, ev) {
    var res = this.view.publiclyTrigger('eventDoubleClick', seg.el[0], seg.event, ev); // can return `false` to cancel
    if (res === false) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
},
```

Finally, go to your fullcalendar initialisation object and specify:

```
eventDoubleClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
}
```

Works in Chrome and IE11.

Comment: Thank you for following up on this old answer with the new version update, I was just looking for how to implement this functionality this morning!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share how I address adding **dblclick** this through the API versus code modification with the fullcalendar version 4 that exposed the property through one object reference.

**Here is the working example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/motogeek/pen/xxxoGGL)**

```
eventRender: function (info) {

  //WON'T ALLOW ALSO WORK WITH single eventClick or single Click Listener
   //info.el.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
     //  alert('DOUBLE CLICK!'+info.event.title);
   //});

  info.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        clickCnt++;         
    if (clickCnt === 1) {
        oneClickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            clickCnt = 0;
            alert('SINGLE CLICK example value grab:' + info.event.title );
        }, 400);
    } else if (clickCnt === 2) {
        clearTimeout(oneClickTimer);
        clickCnt = 0;
        alert('DOUBLE CLICK example value grab:' + info.event.start );

    }          
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With FULLCALENDAR V4:

```
eventRender: function(info) { 
    $(info.el).tooltip({
      title: info.event.title,
    });
    $(info.el).bind('dblclick', function() {
     alert('double click!');
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code can be used for version 6.

```
initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
dateClick: function (info) {
    if (info.dayEl.dblclick) {
        return;
    }

    info.dayEl.dblclick = true;

    info.dayEl.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
        console.log(info)
    });
},
```